# Can't enter invalid view value when using ng-model-optios getterSetter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-forms

If I am using `ng-model-option`'s `getterSetter` with form validation then I cannot enter anything invalid into an input. e.g.

HTML

```
<input type="number" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}" ng-model="ctrl.myVal" min="10">
```

JS

```
this.myVal = function(value) {
  if (value !== undefined) {
    this.actualVal = value;
  } else {
    return this.actualVal;
  }
};
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/dUPXiD1elGfqZSf9x9Bk?p=preview

With that input I cannot enter any number as it would be less than 10.

I am trying to get the same behavior I get without the `getterSetter`. Namely: a user can enter any invalid input in the view but the model will only be set when the input is valid.

Anyone know a workaround I can user to get form validation working with a `getterSetter` or can anyone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the `value` passed to your setter can be `undefined`, tricking your getterSetter into handling a "setter" call as "getter" call.

Changing your condition from `value !== undefined` to `arguments.length` will fix your issue: [Updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/peFdPY1wk5J1jRpVGVUv?p=preview)